# any real world example in RSA with ORDS in oracle

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-ords, vpd, oracle-ras

I'm using ORDS. I'm going to use RAS(real application security) or VPD to control authorization. I read oracle RAS documentation and I didn't catch how to use it with ORDS(without apex). and this is true for using VPD, I created user in `ords.war` but I can't find this user in database and it's just create in ORDS layer, I don't know how to find out which user connected to DB for applying VPD policies.  my question is how to define application users and connect with them ORDS and get response from ORDS.

**For example:**
I have a schema that is rest enabled and authorization is required, now for access it's endpoints I saw some videos that add users with `ords.war` file and login with it and get data, but that's not my problem I want to add some application users (principals in RAS) and set roles to them and apply row level securities. I hope it's be clear.

I'm appreciate in advance.

Comment: The rest service is defined in a schema, when it is called by your ords user, it runs as that db user. So service in HR, runs as HR.

Comment: Right, but I want define multiple api users and apply policies to prevent access any data

Comment: Update your question with some discreet examples, and I'll do my best to address them

Comment: I would start with a db user with the rls and roles desires, then use that schema to define your rest service

Comment: tnx, I would use best method authentication and get token

Comment: So don't use ords user, use built in oauth2 interface

Comment: I'll use it  as authentication way

Comment: @thatjeffsmith how is going on?