# Oracle ORDS get sessions roles

Tags: oracle, oracle-ords

I googled about this question several days but I couldn't find good resources for my question.

I wanna get the list of roles assigned to `ORDS_PUBLIC_USER` after a client authorized with the auth2 method (with client_id and secret_key) to call services. how do that? and my other question is how to get which `client_id`(authorized) and calling services now?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a new OAuth token is requested, a row is added to the table `ORDS_METADATA.SEC_SESSIONS` with that token's information.

In the definition of your REST API, you should be able to get the OAuth token using `UTL_HTTP.GET_HEADER` and look up that token's information in the table. The `STATE` column of `ORDS_METADATA.SEC_SESSIONS` contains JSON that has information about what that token has access to which includes the roles that this token has access to.

You can then use the `USERID` column of the `ORDS_METADATA.SEC_SESSIONS` table to match to the `CLIENT_ID` column of the `ORDS_METADATA.OAUTH_CLIENTS` or `USER_ORDS_CLIENTS` table/view to find the OAuth client that the token is associated with.

Comment: I'll test it. I want it to use for  **VPD policies**,  I asked a question, could you mind take look at it? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66507552/any-real-world-example-in-rsa-with-ords-in-oracle)